# How to upload a file from a Docker container that runs on Fargate to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, containers, aws-fargate

I have a containerized project, the output files are written in the local container (and are deleted when the execution completes), the container runs on Fargate, I want to write a Python script that can call the model that runs on Fargate and get the output file and upload it to an S3 bucket, I'm very new to AWS and Docker, can someone send me an example or share some ideas about how to achieve this?

I think the answer by @jbleduigou makes things complicated, now I can use command to copy the file on my local machine from the container, I just need to write a script to call the model and copy this file out and upload it to S3, I know the concept but couldn't find an example.Anyone can give me an example to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute [S3 Copy command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) via AWS CLI or it's equivalent in [BOTO3 Python client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html).

```
$aws s3 cp /localfolder/localfile.txt s3://mybucket
```

Or equivalent in Python:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.put_object(
    Body='c:\HappyFace.jpg',
    Bucket='examplebucket',
    Key='HappyFace.jpg'
)

print(response)
```

In order for your container to have the right to upload files to S3 you need to setup [Task Execution Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html) and assign it to your task.

Comment: How can this process be written into a Python script?

Comment: See put_object() method documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object Answer updated with an example

Comment: @Anton are there recommended images that have the aws cli installed already, or should we build a Docker image with a step to install the cli?

Comment: Amazon published the official aws-cli image. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-docker.html You can run it as `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash amazon/aws-cli`

Comment: Hello @Anton, thanks for the solution. I have a question: whether is it possible to copy complete directory to s3 instead of single file as mentioned above? For example copy everything from /test/ dir (from local file system) to s3..

Answer (score 2):

Will your python script be sitting outside of your docker container? 
If so you might want to mount an efs volume to your container. 
Copy the output files to that volume inside your container.

Then you can mount the same volume in your ec2 instance running the script.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-create-docker-volume-efs/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: Hi 'mount an efs volume to your container. Copy the output files to that volume inside your container.' This sounds like to set an entry point to the container, but I don't want the script to be ran on ec2, is there other options?

Comment: Hi @jbleduigou Do you have any other suggestions if I want the Python script to run within the container?

Comment: If the script runs within your container you could grant access to s3 by adjusting your IAM role assigned to the Task Definition as Anton said.