# How to upload files to S3 bucket from a docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I have containerized my project that uploads files to S3.

Everything was working fine when I was uploading the files from my local file system.

 I just mounted my container to my local file system, and then uploading stopped.

 The following is the piece of function for uploading the files to the S3 bucket:

```js
// AWS configuration
AWS.config.update({ region: 'ap-northeast-1' });
let s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
.
.
.
function s3uploader(uploadingVideo) {
    // call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
    let uploadParams = { Bucket: "my-bucket", Key: '', Body: '' };
    let file = uploadingVideo;
    console.log(file);

    // Configure the file stream and obtain the upload parameters
    let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('File Error', err);
    });

    uploadParams.Body = fileStream;
    uploadParams.Key = path.basename(file);

    // call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
    s3.upload(uploadParams, function (err, data) {
        console.log("Hello World!")
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        } if (data) {
            console.log("Upload Success", data.Location);
        }
    });
}
```

At the moment, nothing happens when running the container. No error, not even the "Hello World!" part, so I think that `s3` is not being called at the first place.

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104141/how-to-upload-a-file-from-a-docker-container-that-runs-on-fargate-to-s3-bucket), but it wasn't helpful to my case.
I also thought of maybe installing the `aws cli` from `dockerfile` but also didn't succeed with that.

What is exactly missing here, and how to fix it?

Comment: How does this piece of code run ? Did you try running it from the container manually ?

Comment: It's part of a function in the container. (Sorry forgot to mention that.) @AdiDembak

Comment: What type of function ? How do you run it from your local system ?

Comment: Please provide the [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). what is the s3 object and upload Params (Probably the s3 client, however it's worth clarifying)? What language (js / typescript) maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by what type of function? I can add it to my question. I run it when I run the container. It is being called from inside the container.

Comment: @lloyd I just updated my question to include the whole function I am using. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Sorry I can't see what s3 is? `const s3 = new S3({    region: 'ap-southeast-2'});` would be the typescript example of setting s3.

Comment: @lloyd I updated my code in the question to include the missing parts you mentioned. Is it clear now?

Comment: Where is the S3 client getting credentials (in both your host and container setups)?

Comment: @DavidMaze from a local `credentials` file in the same folder of my project